# Is there a triangle which makes dense set of angles by drawing medians?

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry, tiling

**This problem is a restatement of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788189/is-there-a-triangle-which-makes-dense-set-of-angles/2788526#2788526), first announced in MathStackExchange.**

We start with a triangle $T$ in the Euclidean plane and we define $A_n$ as the set of angles of the $6^n$ triangles obtained from the $n$-th [barycentric subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_subdivision) of $T$. (Angles are *geometric* angles, i.e., the angles of $T$ and its children lie in $[0, \pi]$).

What we can say about set $A=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$?

Is there a specific predefined triangle for which $A$ is dense on $(0,\pi)$?

If no, does there exist another simple alternative to this iterative procedure, i.e., barycentric subdivision, using other [concurrent lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_lines) in triangles, which achieves our goal?

Comment: The sentence starting with "In $(n+1)$-th step" sounds  obscure, even grammatically. Is $A_n$ a set of angles or a set of triangles? What is the meaning of  "$\lim_n A_n$"?  What is the meaning of "$A$ is dense on $(0,\pi)$"? What is "our goal"? Thank you

Comment: Is perhaps $A_n$  the set of $6^n$ triangles of the $n$-th barycentric subdivision of $T$?

Comment: @PietroMajer $A_n$ is set of angles of all triangles till $n$-th step (you're true: $6^n$ triangles in $n$-th step +$6^{n-1}$ in $n-1$-th step+...+1=$\sum_{i=0}^{n} 6^i$ tiangles) ,leads $A_n$ has $3×\sum_{i=0}^{n} 6^i$ angles. Our goal is to find a dense $A$ on $(0,\pi)$

Comment: OK, so $A=\cup_n A_n$, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to the second question is **yes**, for any non-flat triangle $T$, the set of angles $A$ is dense in $(0, \pi)$. This follows from a stronger result of Barany et al. [Theorem 1, 1]:

> > **Theorem**. Successive barycentric subdivisions of a non-flat triangle contain
> >     triangles which, to within a similarity, approximate arbitrarily closely any
> >     given triangle.

Here is a nice divulgative [article](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fc-2017-06)  on the dynamics of iterated barycentric subdivisions. It also has a list of further readings on the topic. 
(*The joy of barycentric subdivision*, by Bill Casselman)-

---

[1] I. Barany, A. Beardon and T. Carne, "Barycentric subdivision of triangles and semigroups of Möbius maps", 1996. [MR1401715](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1401715).